# Nonclustered Index Insert

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table like this:

```
create table SomeTable
(
    id int identity(1, 1) not null primary key clustered,
    SomeString1 varchar(50) not null,
    SomeString2 varchar(50) not null
)
go

create nonclustered index IX_SomeString1
on SomeTable(SomeString1)
go
```

If I was to do this:

```
insert into SomeTable(SomeString1, SomeString2)
values('foo', 'bar')
go
```

And view the actual execution plan, I only see a **Clustered Index Insert**.  Why am I not seeing a **Nonclustered Index Insert** in the execution plan?

Comment: I'm guessing because until you hit a certain cardinality and rowcount threshold, it's not worthwhile to maintain the stats on the nonclustered index.

If you have a single row in a table, the optimizer knows it's not going to use that index so it's not maintaining it.

Comment: @JNK But if I do a `select * from SomeTable where String1 = 'foo'`, then I see that the query optimizer does in fact choose the index `IX_SomeString1` for an index seek.  So it must be updating that index, no?

Comment: You can look at the stats for it and see.  It may be a shortcoming in the execution plan display, too.  Have you checked the xml?

Comment: You will have one if you insert more than one row with a single insert statement. Like this `insert into SomeTable(SomeString1, SomeString2) values('foo', 'bar'),('foo', 'bar')`. But if the optimizer knows that you will only insert one row it is not there (even if the source is a table instead of `values`). I don't know why.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Tried that, still no explicit insert into the Nonclustered Index.  Just the Clustered Index insert.

Comment: Perhaps a SQL Server 2012 thing. Anyway, as Remus said it is there in the xml plan.

Comment: @JNK XML is checked, there is no Physical Operation of a Nonclustered Index Insert.

Comment: SQL Server can use [either a wide or a narrow plan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/07/27/680518.aspx) depending on how many rows are affected. This controls whether the index maintenance operations happen separately and are shown up in the plan as separate operations or together and show up as part of the CI operation.

Comment: @MartinSmith Great explanation and I did not know that.  Thanks for the link and comment.  That should be an answer, I believe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a single row insert you get a narrow/per-row plan

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(SomeString1, SomeString2)
SELECT TOP 1 type, type
FROM master..spt_values
```

[image: Narrow plan]

If you select the Clustered Index Insert Operator and View the properties window you can see the same information as shown in the XML.

[image: Properties Window]

If you try for 1,000 rows

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(SomeString1, SomeString2)
SELECT TOP 1000 type, type
FROM master..spt_values
```

You get a different wide/per-index plan with the operations split out separately

[image: Wide Plan]

See [Wide vs. Narrow Plans](https://web.archive.org/web/20151023181154/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/07/27/680518.aspx) or [Craig Freedman's blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/optimized-non-clustered-index-maintenance-in-per-index-plans) for more information about the two

Answer (score 6):

Never trust the graphical plan display, is only for newbies. Pros always look at the XML. The NC operation is right there:

```
<Update DMLRequestSort="false">
  <Object Database="[testdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SomeTable]" Index="[PK__SomeTabl__3213E83F4AAF1C98]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
  <Object Database="[testdb]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SomeTable]" Index="[IX_SomeString1]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "only for newbies" by a long stretch.

Comment: My 'newb' comment is not about the skill of the viewer, is about experience: those who had been burned by the liberal 'omissions' of the graphical plans know better than to trust it. This applies even more so to [deadlock graphs](http://rusanu.com/2010/05/12/the-puzzle-of-u-locks-in-deadlock-graphs/).

Comment: FWIW the graphical plan makes it much easier (for the most part) to find the time bottleneck by following the execution time of the operators sequentially until there's a dropoff. So pros do use the graphical plan for that purpose as well (besides looking at the XML plan when needed).